# On the BibLaTEX fields containing references to the ZBmath (formerly Zentralblatt für Mathematik und ihre Grenzgebiete) reviews

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex

This question is perhaps more on the use of certain parameters in BibTEX than on the use of TEX/LaTEX itself: nevertheless I think it could be of some help to other persons who, like myself, need to redact large bibliographies.

In order to list information on the existence of a review in the ZBmath database on a bibliographic item, I am aware of the existence of the following three parameters:

```
...
zbl = {},
zbmath = {},
zblnumber = {},
...
```

Until a few years ago, only the last one seems to have been used (possibly my opinion is biased by the heavy use of Jabref I do), therefore I'd like to ask

1. why the other ones have been introduced,
2. if there's one of them which is preferable to use.

**P. S.** Finally, let me point out that the American Mathematical Society always codes the analogous information in the univocal parameter `mrnumber = {},` which works perfectly in many bibliography styles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after a few months, having realized that my question is more on the use and meaning of certain BibTEX parameters than on TEX/LaTEX coding, I decided to ask it directly to the zbMATH: this is an excerpt of the answer by Dr. Isabel Beckenbach

> thank you for your question. You are right that there are two different
> identifiers for a zbMATH item. Namely the zbl number (with a dot), which
> is main identifier used externally, and the DE number (just an integer),
> which is used internally. Every document has a DE number from the
> beginning on but it might not have a zbl number. The zbl number is
> assigned if a document is finished in our production process. If you
> search for newer documents, you might have noticed that they have an
> identifier without a dot and the older ones have an identifier with a
> dot (or even with two dots for the Jahrbuch für Mathematik items).

> For example this newer book has only a DE number and no zbl number:

```
@Book{zbMATH07407731,
Author = {Gomi, Kiyonori},
Title = {Topological {{\(K\)}}-theory. {Basics}, calculations and
applications to topological insulators (to appear)},
ISBN = {978-3-11-067239-8},
Year = {2026},
Publisher = {Berlin: De Gruyter},
Language = {English},
Keywords = {19-01,19Lxx},
zbMATH = {7407731}
}
```

> We changed the bibtex output format a while ago and decided to display
> both the DE number (under the key zbMATH) and the zbl number (if it
> exists).

Regarding the `zblnumber = {...}` parameter of the `aomplain` BibTEX style (i. e. the style used by the [Annals of Mathematics](https://annals.math.princeton.edu)), Dr. Beckenback simply said it was a choice of the editors to use it as the key for the zbMATH identifier, and the zbMATH Organisation has nothing to do with their decision.

Well, I hope this answer could be useful to someone else.